# Transform an array into a string while keeping the [ ] inside the string

Tags: javascript

I have an array of integers

```
element= [12,456]
```

I would like to transform this into

```
desired_output = "[12,456]"
```

I tried toString but it fails. For example `element.toString()` outputs `"12,456"` which is not what I want.

It's tricky, I want to keep the [ and the ] inside the string.

Comment: `JSON.stringify([12,456])`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti please put a formal answer so I can give you points:) thanks it worked

Comment: by the way is it possible to go the other way around like move from  "[12,456]"  to [12,456] ?

Comment: found it: it's json.parse

Comment: @mplungjan I tried but it seems I did not know json was the key, once you sue this keyword the answer abound! I was instead getting strange splits and joins and none working.

Comment: I did not use JSON. I searched `convert array to string javascript keep brackets` which is almost identical to your title - same dupe shows when I do `javascript Transform array into string keeping bracket`

Comment: strange, my bad then, good lesson for the future. To be fair most of me 1000+ come from Ruby and Rails. I'm very unfamiliar with vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 2):

This might work:

```
JSON.stringify(YourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
desired = `[${a.join(',')}]`
console.log(desired) //"[1,2,3]"
```